# How to check if visitors are connected to facebook

Tags: php, facebook

Well im working on a small php script and i want to make a test to see if the visitor is logged to facebook in his computer using php.
I want to do it in these way:

```
If (USER IS CONNECTED){echo "yes";}else{echo "no";}
```

Is it possible? if yes how can i do it ?

Comment: http://www.tomanthony.co.uk/tools/detect-social-network-logins/ This website is doing it but in javascript ! Are u sure that i cant do it in php ?

Comment: correct.. the javascript version is making ajax requests and including scripts.  you can do it in javascript and send an ajax request back to your server though, store something in a session..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no documented way to achieve this. The JS is there for a reason (AJAX requests).
The article you're referring to is exploiting redirects after login, and  doesn't even work (fails to recognize you're logged into Twitter). Something that starts with "I found a way to abuse" shouldn't be taken into consideration. 
That's unethical, it exploits a loophole that will be fixed sooner or later, and I call it cracking. 
Why would you need this information anyhow?

Comment: Thank you ! I need those information because i want to hide the facebook comment and like box when the visitor is not logged in !

Comment: if you hide them, users won't login into their accounts to comment or like, and you'll lose social signals!...Just leave them there ;)

Comment: They will appear when the visitors is already logged in and i will hide them when he is not and i will show the website like and comment system instead of facebook ! so in this way i will keep google visiting my pages and consider them as an active pages do you understand me ?